# implementing a timeout when reading a file with Delphi

Tags: delphi, file-io, timeout, delphi-2006

I have an app written in Delphi 2006 that regularly reads from a disk file located elsewhere on a network (100Mb ethernet).  Occasionally the read over the network takes a very long time (like 20 secs) and the app freezes, as the read is done from an idle handler in the main thread.

OK, I could put the read operation into it's own thread, but what I would like to know is whether it is possible to specify a timeout for a file operation, so that you can give up and go and do something else, or report the fact that the read has snagged a bit earlier than 20 seconds later.

```
function ReadWithTimeout (var Buffer     ;
                              N       : integer ; 
                              Timeout : integer) : boolean ;

begin
Result := false
try
    SetReadTimeout (Timeout) ;          //  <==========================???
    FileStream.Read (Buffer, N) ;
    Result := true ;
except 
    ... 
    end ;
end ;
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Open the file for [*asynchronous* access](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365683.aspx) by including the `File_Flag_Overlapped` flag when you call `CreateFile`. Pass in a `TOverlapped` record when you call `ReadFile`, and if the read doesn't complete immediately, the function will return early. You can control how long you wait for the read to complete by calling `WaitForSingleObject` on the event you store in the `TOverlapped` structure. You can even use `MsgWaitForMultipleObjects` to wait; then you can be notified as soon as the read completes *or* a message arrives, whichever comes first, so your program doesn't need to hang at all. After you finish processing messages, you can check again whether the I/O is complete with `GetOverlappedResult`, resume waiting, or give up on the I/O by calling `CancelIo`. Make sure you read the documentation for all those functions carefully; asynchronous I/O isn't trivial.

Comment: I'm sure it would, but I'll leave that to someone more capable (or more motivated) than I, @Workshop. As I said, it's not trivial, so I'm not about to compose an example on the spot.

Answer (score 0):

After you've moved the read operation to a thread, you could store the value returned by timeGetTime before reading:

```
isReading := true;
try
  startedAt := timeGetTime;
  FileStream.Read (Buffer, N);
  ...
finally
  isReading := false;
end;
```

and check in the idle handler if it's taken too long.

eg:

```
function ticksElapsed( FromTicks, ToTicks : cardinal ) : cardinal;
begin
  if FromTicks < ToTicks
    then Result := ToTicks - FromTicks
    else Result := ( high(cardinal) - FromTicks ) + ToTicks; // There was a wraparound
end;

...

if isReading and ( ticksElapsed( startedAt, timeGetTime ) > 10 * 1000 ) // Taken too long? ~10s
then // Do something
```

Comment: Problem is: if the read snags in the thread, it will be holding the file open, so even if I detect that it has taken longer than 1 sec say, I wouldn't be able to retry until the thread had reached the finally clause, i.e. until the 20 seconds had elapsed.

Comment: Well, depending on the sharing mode you used to open the file, you should be able to open a second handle to it, and try in parallel with a different thread. You should be careful, though, with issues like overwriting shared data or starting too many threads.